How to setup tensorflow 2.14 with GPU/CUDA on Ubuntu Image
I am trying to figure out how to make a docker image (using a dockerfile) that has tensorflow-2.14 with cudatoolkit-11.5 and cudnn-8.9.7 since I believe that these versions all work together to allow GPU useage. I am trying to make the docker image and see that it does, but I am stuck. After fighting with this for the last 2 days and reading everything I could find (most of which is all outdated) I think I am close, but can't quite get it across the finish line. Here is my docker file
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER test-user

# update apt and get miniconda
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh


# install miniconda
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
RUN mkdir /root/.conda && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
COPY gpu_check.py /root/gpu_check.py

# create conda environment
RUN conda init bash \
    && . ~/.bashrc \
    && conda create --name tf python=3.11.0 \
    && conda activate tf \
    && yes | conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.5 cudnn=8.9.7 \
    && yes | pip install tensorflow==2.14.0

SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "tf", "/bin/bash", "-c"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "conda init; source ~/.bashrc; conda activate tf; python3 /root/gpu_check.py"]

my little script to see if tensorflow can see the GPU
import tensorflow as tf; 
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

and my error
(base) me@LAPTOP:~/dockerBuilds$ docker run tf-test
no change     /root/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /root/miniconda3/bin/conda
no change     /root/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /root/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /root/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /root/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /root/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /root/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /root/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /root/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /root/.bashrc
No action taken.

CondaError: Run 'conda init' before 'conda activate'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/gpu_check.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf; 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

so it's just some silly issue with me getting docker to just run things like a terminal. If I use ENTRYPOINT["bash"] and open up the container then I can switch to conda tf environment and run the python script. The python scripts shows tensorflow cannot see the GPU (sadness).
So the main question is "what am I doing wrong in my dockerfile?" and bonus points if you know why tensorflow cannot see my GPU (I have it working in my WSL2 environment, so maybe I am just forgetting something?).
Here is with the EntryPoint and docker with all gpus that show tensorflow is installed in the conda tf environment (but no GPUs found) if that helps any
(base) me@LAPTOP:~/dockerBuilds$ docker run -it --gpus all tf-test
(base) root@18c6e0d1455a:/# ls
Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh  boot  etc   lib    media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
bin                                dev   home  lib64  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
(base) root@18c6e0d1455a:/# bash
(base) root@18c6e0d1455a:/# conda activate tf
(tf) root@18c6e0d1455a:/# cd /root
(tf) root@18c6e0d1455a:~# ls
gpu_check.py  miniconda3
(tf) root@18c6e0d1455a:~# python gpu_check.py 
2024-05-27 17:48:29.854552: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-05-27 17:48:29.895884: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-05-27 17:48:29.895936: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-05-27 17:48:29.895985: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-05-27 17:48:29.911960: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-05-27 17:48:29.912996: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-27 17:48:31.031334: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-05-27 17:48:31.914073: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:268] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_FOUND: named symbol not found
[]


have you installed the nvidia docker extensions and tested that one of the nvidia containers works first?

Not solving this problem directly, but you could also use the tensorflow docker image directly. How to use on the TF pages.

do you mean this page? https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-containers-runtime/
I tried and it gave me errors when I tried updating apt... Somethung to do with public keys and InReleases

maybe the best solution is to abandon WSL2 and use a VM or actual Linux OS?

as for the tensorflow docker image, it does not see my GPU either
